# How to properly parse multipart/byteranges responses using typescript/javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest, multipart

I'm new to TypeScript/JavaScript and I'm trying to do multipart range requests ([RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)) for different parts of a binary file, using TypeScript and XMLHttpRequest 2.

According to [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233), a multipart/byteranges response has the following:

```
 HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
 Date: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 06:25:24 GMT
 Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT
 Content-Length: 1741
 Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES

 --THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
 Content-Type: application/pdf
 Content-Range: bytes 500-999/8000

 ...the first range...
 --THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
 Content-Type: application/pdf
 Content-Range: bytes 7000-7999/8000

 ...the second range
 --THIS_STRING_SEPARATES--
```

I see two options:

1. Treat the body of the response as binary data array (set `XMLHttpRequest.responseType = "arraybuffer"`), convert the boundary string into binary, search in the binary data array for each body part delimited by the boundary-string-converted-to-binary, extract the headers for each payload and converted them to string? or,
2. Similar to above, but treat the body as a string (set `XMLHttpRequest.responseType = "text"`), identify the body parts delimited by the boundary-string, and convert the payloads to binary data arrays?

What is the proper way to handle/parse such responses in javascript/typescript, since the response contains multiple body parts, each with its own headers (string) and payload (binary)?

Is there a simpler way?

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering why `Content-Length` is `1741` in this case. As I understand it, it is the number of bytes of the whole body, but it does not come up to `1741`. Maybe because it is an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not even sure how you'd do it using an `"arraybuffer"` response type, but I've used this before to parse multipart/byteranges responses:

```
function parseMultipartBody (body, boundary) {
  return body.split(`--${boundary}`).reduce((parts, part) => {
    if (part && part !== '--') {
      const [ head, body ] = part.trim().split(/\r\n\r\n/g)
      parts.push({
        body: body,
        headers: head.split(/\r\n/g).reduce((headers, header) => {
          const [ key, value ] = header.split(/:\s+/)
          headers[key.toLowerCase()] = value
          return headers
        }, {})
      })
    }
    return parts
  }, [])
}
```

And for using it with an XMLHttpRequest it'd probably look something like this:

```
const client = new XMLHttpRequest()
client.open('GET', 'example.pdf', true)
client.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=500-999,7000-7999')
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status === 206) {
    const boundary = client.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').match(/boundary=(.+)$/i)[1]
    if (boundary) console.log('PARTS', parseMultipartBody(client.resposeText, boundary))
  }
}
client.send()
```

The output from your example response would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "body": "...the first range...",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/pdf",
      "content-range": "bytes 500-999/8000"
    }
  },
  {
    "body": "...the second range",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/pdf",
      "content-range": "bytes 7000-7999/8000"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this function! I think it'll actually return a first and fourth elements right, (0) `{ body: undefined, headers: { '': undefined } },` and (3) `{ body: undefined, headers: { '--': undefined } }`, because it'll try to parse the final line (which is a boundary, `--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES--`) and the split before the first boundary.

Comment: Completely noob question... where does the javascript go? I have my `multipart/byteranges` content. The browser downloads all of it in 1 file (with the 2 sets of headers and the separators). Do I need to put the javascript above the first separator?